# Drop Files Into Dynamically Generated Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to change the `src` of a dynamically generated placeholder image by dropping another image on it, but I can't get data from the dropped image. I've tried a couple ways and neither works.

Method 1:

```
console.log(e.dataTransfer);
```

Returns *undefined*

Method 2:

```
console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length);
```

Returns no files. Here's a working sample of my probem: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znc6p5bs/). What am I missing?

Update:
As @Marcel points out, the drop event receives data when users drag it from their computer, but doesn't get any data from images loaded in the browser. My end goal is to have users drag images from another browser tab or window and update the placeholder URL with the dropped image's URL.

Comment: It works if you drop a file from your computer and not already in the page.

Comment: Well that's unexpected. My end goal is to make it possible to drag images from another browser tab or window and use its URL. I don't want to have to upload files that users drag from their local storage. Makes me wonder if my approach is way off. Any idea how to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is looking to achieve the same functionality, I was able to do it with the code bits below.

```
var droppedImage = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
var imageURL = $(droppedImage).attr('src');
```

It works with images on the same page & images dragged from another browser window/tab.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1sv9pv3r/)